# How can I change the default permissions for `/run/named/session.key` in Bind9?

Tags: bind

I'm using `nsupdate -l` from a local script to update DNS records in Bind9.

It's working, except, I need for PHP to have read access to the key at `/run/named/session.key`.

I can give PHP access by changing the group of the key to the PHP process user and adding `g+r` read permissions to it, but the permissions revert back to `bind:bind` with `chmod 600` every time Bind is restarted.

Is there a way to configure the default permissions in Bind9 for `/run/named/session.key` so that a different group owns it, and group read is enabled (`chmod 640`) when Bind is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file **/run/named/session.key** is created by bind with 0600 permissions. If you want to change to 0640, you could "override" the systemd script for **bind** with

```
systemctl edit named
```

In this way, you can add instructions to the ones of the unit file for  **bind** without fear of losing the configuration when updating the **bind** package as this configuration is saved in **/etc/systemd/system/named.service.d/override.conf**.

This works for me to change the file permissions:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/sleep 2; /usr/bin/chmod 640 /run/named/session.key'
```

Without the sleep for 2 seconds, **ExecStartPost** executes before **/var/run/session.key** is created in my **bind**. The waiting for 2 seconds is not very elegant, you could try waiting for the existence of **/run/named/session**.key before changing the permissions

Of course you should execute these commands to update the systems configuration and restart the service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart named
```